# I want to change the value of a domain model variable based on the current date

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have created a domain model object called **Report** and gave it several variables such as:

```
Date dateCreated
Boolean expired
```

I then create instances of the object like this:

```
def report = new Report(id: 1, dateCreated: currentDate, expired: false)
```

Saving these instances works fine, but I want to have the `expired` variable change to 'true' automatically once the `dateCreated` variable is 24 hours old. This really matters for the `report.gsp` site that I am working with but it seems like a bad practice to put an "if" loop inside of the .gsp if I can help it. I need to know where I should be triggering this event so that the new value for the expired variable persists.

Comment: Turns out the controller is the place to add this. I will be providing the answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value to automatically update in the database without anything special triggering that in your Grails app then you are going to need to write some kind of function in the database to do that.  If it is ok to just have the expired attribute updated when when the object is updated by the Grails app then you could do something like this:

```
class Report {
    Date dateCreated
    Boolean expired

    def beforeUpdate() {
        // expired if created more than 7 days ago...
        expired = dateCreated < (new Date() - 7)
    }
}
```

Of course you can do the same sort of thing imperatively if you want...

```
class SomeController {
    def someAction() {
        def report = Report.get(params.id)
        report.expired = report.dateCreated < (new Date() - 7)
        // ...
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer is similar to what I ended up doing when I solved this problem. Your first example inside the beforeUpdate() did NOT work for me, but your second example of adding an action to a controller is pretty close to what I had done.

Comment: Note that in recent versions of Grails/GORM I would do this differently and would take advantage of the events system to get this code out of the domain class.  https://github.com/jeffbrown/gorm-events-demo/blob/261f25652e5fead8563ed83f7903e52dfb37fb40/src/main/groovy/gorm/events/demo/listener/AuditListener.groovy